# как работает данный сценарий?

Tags: python

столкнулся с препятствиями при изучении ООП python'а. до меня не доходит, почему этот код работает:

```
class Smth:
   
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def num(self):
        print(self.x)

p = Smth(5)

p.num()
```

не понимаю зачем здесь нужен метод **init** и зачем мы пишем self.x = x
всем ответившим огромное спасибо!

Comment: __инит__ это конструктор класса. Этот метод будет вызываться каждый раз при создании нового экземпляра объекта. Собсно, когда вы создадите такой (p = Smth(5)), сработает код self.x = x, т.е. 5 припишем свойству х объекта Smth. Дальше в методе num будем использовать это свойство

Comment: Я ниже написал свой ответ, если вам всё понятно, то отметьте его в качестве решения вопроса, если не понятно, то давайте я вам ещё раз расскажу

Comment: здравствуйте, большое спасибо за такую отзывчивость, все теперь стало ясно! но одно я не могу понять - если мы объявили self.x в методе, то мы можем вызвать эту переменную в любой части кода, несмотря на область видимости? или я что-то не догоняю

Comment: @АлександрБурейко в ООП области видимости работают немного не так, как обычно. Если у нас нет класса то существуют глобальные и локальные переменные, с этим всё понятно. Я сам ещё не читал классы в питоне, но я думаю, что self указывает на свойства класса. Свойства - это те же самые переменные, но они живут только внутри класса ( например, рост человека привязан к конкретному человеку и если мы напишем Александр.рост то получим ваш рост, а Алексей.рост - мой рост ). Таким образом при рождении ( объявлении ) переменной выделяется область памяти и все свойства живут связанными с переменной р

Comment: точно ! @АлександрБурейко я добавил в самый конец программы ещё строчку ```print( p.x )``` и как вы думаете, какой результат ? :)

Comment: @alex спасибо большое еще раз. полагаю, что print(p.x) даст 5)

Comment: верно, свойство хранится там же где и экземпляр класса. Свойство будет хранится до тех пор, пока жива переменная ```р```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Smth:  # Это объявление класса или типа
   
    def __init__(self, x): # Как ужe написал @entithat
                           # эта функция запускается, когда объявляется
                           # переменная p ( ниже )
        self.x = x         # Здесь мы присвоили свойству значение 5
                           # при объявлении переменной p ( чуть ниже )
    def num(self):         # Это метод. Если у нас есть переменная
        print(self.x)      # типа Smth, значит все переменные
                           # или экземпляры могут вызвать данный метод 

p = Smth( 5 ) # В этой строке мы говорим, что будет переменная 
              # p типа Smth  
p.num()       # вызывается метод класса и печатается свойство p ( т.е. 5 )
```